# is there a length limit to group_concat or another reason why it would not work on a text field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

First, here is the query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(title) title, GROUP_CONCAT(description) description,
skill_id, count(*)

FROM jobs j
INNER JOIN job_feed_details d
ON j.id = d.job_id
JOIN jobs_skills js
ON j.id = js.job_id
    WHERE moderated = 1
    group by skill_id
```

Everything works as expected except the description field only returns one result, instead of a concatenation of all results. I suspect this is because the description is a `text` field, but I cannot find anything about why concatenation would not work with a text field.

Anyone know why this would not work?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The group_concat result length is limited(truncated) to the value of the **group_concat_max_len** system variable. The default value of this variable is 1024.

If you want change the value of the variable the syntax is:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```

More info [Mysql 5 docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: ..limited by bytes, not characters. So if you are using text in utf8, result is truncated after ~363 character (see [Is group_concat_max_len in bytes or characters?](http://ebergen.net/wordpress/2011/09/05/is-group_concat_max_len-in-bytes-or-characters/))