# database select query logic with one table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have one table booking that have value like belw

```
id           email 
1           a@a.com
2           a@a.com 
3           b@b.com
4           c@c.com
5.          c@c.com
```

I want output like this

```
email       id
a@a.com     1,2
b@b.com     3
c@c.com     4,5
```

can you suggest how i can do this.

Answer (score 4):

In `MysQL`, use `GROUP_CONCAT` function

```
SELECT email, GROUP_CONCAT(id) id
FROM tableName
GROUP BY email
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bda6/3)

Comment: @user1619419 no, check the records again `:D`

Comment: please check below link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445048/is-there-a-length-limit-to-group-concat-or-another-reason-why-it-would-not-work