# Is it possible to condense the result of multiple rows into a set object on one row in an SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm refactoring some code, and looking at ways to try and improve both readability and performance.

One item that bugs me is situations where I need a join statement with multiple objects on one side.  For example...

```
Foo Schema         Bar 2 Schema
--------------     ---------------
id                 id
data               fooId
                   data

Result from Search:
---------------------
id   barId    fooData
1    1        ...
1    2        ...
1    3        ...
2    4        ...
3    5        ...
```

My end result, when querying for object Foo, needs to be an object Foo containing the id's (or objects fetched based on the id's) that are related.

Currently, I wind up having to condense multiple rows at the PHP level, adding bar id's to Foo until the foo id changes.  It's a bit ugly, but it does work.  What'd I'd like to reduce my result set to would be:

```
Result from Search:
---------------------
id   barIds   fooData
1    [1,2,3]  ...
2    4        ...
3    5        ...
```

Is there any way to do this at the SQL level?  (As a note, I'm not looking for the literal string 1, 2, 3, I want an array consisting of the id's 1, 2, and 3 -- but if I have to take a string and then transform, I can do)

As an aside, my intent is to combine this with the PDO::fetch_class to let me instantiate the class in a single line instead of spending time writing many lines of cookie-cutter code to load the properties of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking into using `GROUP_CONCAT`.  This will combine all the bar ids together.  Something like this:

```
SELECT F.Id, GROUP_CONCAT(B.Id) BarIds, F.data
FROM Foo F 
   INNER JOIN Bar B ON F.Id = B.FooId
GROUP BY F.Id
```

If you'd like to get your exact format, try using `CONCAT`:

```
CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(B.Id),']') BarIds
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7669/2).

**--EDIT--**

If there is a concern over the length of characters stored by default with GROUP_CONCAT (check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445135/1073631) out), another alternative approach would be to mimic the behavior of GROUP_CONCAT by doing something like this:

```
SELECT Id, BarIds, Data
FROM (
    SELECT F.Id,  
      MAX(@barIdsCombined:=IF(@prevFoodId=F.Id,
                          CONCAT(@barIdsCombined,',',B.Id),
                         B.Id)) BarIds, 
      F.data,
      @prevFoodId:=F.Id
    FROM Foo F 
       INNER JOIN Bar B ON F.Id = B.FooId
        JOIN (SELECT @barIdsCombined:='') t
    GROUP BY F.Id
  ) t
```

Comment: Beware of using `GROUP_CONCAT` because it has a very low artificial limit.  You can update it (`group_concat_max_len`).  I have gone down the road of using MySQL for aggregation including `GROUP_CONCAT`.  Experience tells me that it's generally much better to aggregate with the querying language as MySQL has very limited powers

Comment: I only used the [ and ] to indicate that it was probably going to hit PHP as an array, which -- IIRC -- is how PDO handles the SQL set datatype.

Comment: @ExplosionPills By 'aggregate with the querying language', I assume you mean PHP?  Is it really that great an idea -- it seems like this would be a great place for SQL to be able to work some magic to reduce overhead with background query optimization and caching.

Comment: @RonLugge -- imho, unless you have to worry about having a long set of data returned (usually varchar based), group_concat is the way to go.  I included another option which mimics that behavior, but I rarely run into an issue with group_concat.  With that said, if you are using it on varchar fields with lots of text, then you could run into an issue if you don't up the max_len.  Best of luck!