# mysql query get multiple attachments with multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a clarification table and a file uploads table where all the attachments with respect to the clarification is placed. I am using left join and getting the result like this.

```
clarificationid - 1 | attachment 1
clarificationid - 1 | attachment 2
clarificationid - 2 | no attachment
```

Is there any way to get result like

```
clarificationid - 1 | attachment 1,atttachment 2
clarificationid - 2 | no attachment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT`,but be aware of that there is limit of characters in [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) but this can be increased for help follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445048/is-there-a-length-limit-to-group-concat-or-another-reason-why-it-would-not-work)

```
SELECT clarificationid ,
GROUP_CONCAT(attachment)
FROM 
`table`
GROUP BY clarificationid
```